# How to integrate characteristic functions

Tags: maxima, integral, calculus

The following integral does is not evaluated by Maxima:

```
integrate(charfun(x<1/2), x, 0, 1);
```

Is there a different trick to make it work, or is it simply un-implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The share package `abs_integrate` can integrate some expressions containing `signum`, `abs`, and `unit_step`. In this case you can write `charfun(x < 1/2)` in terms of `signum(1/2 - x)` and then `abs_integrate` can handle it.

You'll need to load `abs_integrate`. Note that `abs_integrate` modifies the behavior of `integrate`; there isn't a separate `abs_integrate` function to call.

```
(%i2) load (abs_integrate) $
(%i3) integrate (signum (1/2 - x), x, 0, 1);
(%o3)                           0
(%i4) integrate (signum (1/2 - x), x, -1, 1);
(%o4)                           1
(%i5) foo (e) := (1 + signum(e))/2;
                               1 + signum(e)
(%o5)                foo(e) := -------------
                                     2
(%i6) integrate (foo (1/2 - x), x, 0, 1);
                                1
(%o6)                           -
                                2
(%i7) integrate (foo (1/2 - x), x, -1, 1);
                                3
(%o7)                           -
                                2
```

Note that `foo` corresponds to `charfun` here.